# how to check if new systemd user have permission to execute a binary file

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I realize this question has been asked/answered a few times before, but haven't been able to solve it.. I have the following systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My client service
ConditionPathExists=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myservice
Group=myservice
LimitNOFILE=1024

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
startLimitIntervalSec=60

WorkingDirectory=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client
ExecStart=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client

# make sure log directory exists and owned by syslog
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/myclient
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown syslog:adm /var/log/myclient
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 /var/log/myclient
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have then created a new user:

`useradd myservice -s /sbin/nologin -M`

but when I try to run the systemd daemon I get:

`Process: 11956 ExecStart=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`

All of this worked fine on my local machine (running Ubuntu 16.04), but when I try on a scaleway server (also running Ubuntu 16.04) then I get the above error. I'm 100% certain all the paths are correct.

I'm certain the myservice user alreasy was successfully created, because if I try to run: `useradd myservice -s /sbin/nologin -M` then I get `useradd: user 'myservice' already exists`

When I check the permissions then I get this:

```
$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/myclient.service 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 790 Sep 14 11:48 /lib/systemd/system/myclient.service
$ ls -l /root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9167576 Sep 14 12:02 /root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client
```

If I run the app by simply running `/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client` then it works and run as it should.. so it seems the problem is related to `myservice` not having permission to run either the `client` binary or the `myclient.service` systemd daemon..

I have also tried to `chown myservice client` but the result is the same.. I believe running `usermod -a -G root myservice` is the same as simply running the systemd daemon as root instead of a separate user..

I really don't know what other steps I can take to make sure that the files are executed by the `myservice` user rather than the `root` user.. Any help would be much appreciated

---

edit to address Mark's comments:

The output is extremely long.. I took the initial one, and then I kept scrolling until I believe I reached the latest error:

```
Sep 14 11:49:17 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:18 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:20 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:20 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:22 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:23 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:24 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:24 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:51 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:51 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Stopped My client service.
Sep 14 11:49:51 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:51 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:49:51 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/myclient.service:14] Unknown lvalue 'startLimitIntervalSec' in se
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Starting My client service...
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Started My client service.
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 14 11:51:12 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 11:51:23 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 11:51:23 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Stopped My client service.

...

Sep 14 12:21:36 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Started My client service.
Sep 14 12:21:36 myapp-c1 systemd[13245]: myclient.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client: 
Sep 14 12:21:36 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 14 12:21:36 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 14 12:21:36 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Stopped My client service.
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Starting My client service...
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Started My client service.
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 14 12:21:46 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Stopped My client service.
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Starting My client service...
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Started My client service.
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 14 12:21:56 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 12:22:07 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: myclient.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 12:22:07 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Stopped My client service.
Sep 14 12:22:07 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Starting My client service...
Sep 14 12:22:07 myapp-c1 systemd[1]: Started My client service.
```

You're right, I added user group in mixed order.. this is the output when I run the command:

```
$ grep myservice /etc/group
myservice:1000:myservice
```

Note that I used `myservice`, I don't think I'm supposed to use `myclient`?

Comment: Did you check `journalctl` output, in particular `journalctl -u myclient.service` ?

Comment: `grep myclient /etc/group` Does the group you are trying to execute the process as actually exist? You did not use `-g`, `-U` or `--user-group` options to `useradd`.

Comment: @MarkStosberg thanks for looking at it, I have made an edit providing the output to these two commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it runs from the CLI but not from `systemd` on the same machine. this is a variation of the related FAQ: [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645).

The most likely cause is an environment variable set in one case but not another. Also compare the output of `systemctl show your-unit-unit.service` between the system where it works the one that it doesn't.

Also confirm that `Type=` matches the kind of service you are running, documented in `man systemd.service`, and review the documentation for your binary to see under what circumstances it would exit with a status code of 203.

Finally, check `ls -lthd /root` on the server. Typically the `/root` directory has restrictive permissions set that only allow root to access files under it, but you are trying to run a file as a underneath there on your server (where it fails), but not at home (where it succeeds). Moving the code to `/home/myservice` would resolve that issue.

Comment: I just compared `systemctl show your-unit-unit.service`, the output was identical, minus the path difference (but made sure the path is correct) and one thing that I found quite strange: locally (where it works) one output said `ExecStart={ path=/home/me/code/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client ; argv[]=/home/me/code/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client ; ign`, but on the server (where it doesn't work) the output was `ExecStart={ path=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client ; argv[]=/root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client ; ignore_errors=no ; star`

Comment: I do wonder, what is your opinion about just running systemd as root instead of creating a new user?

Comment: See updated answer. Also, I strongly suggest running the app as the user, not as root-- much better security.

Comment: `ls -lthd /root` shows `drwx------ 5 root root 4.0K Sep 14 12:06 /root`. However, `ls -lthd /root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client` shows `-rwxr-xr-x 1 myservice root 8.8M Sep 14 12:02 /root/go/src/github.com/me/myapp/client/client`. I would think that means it was okay if it was located within root? That being said, I have tried moving the binary to `/home/` as you suggested - here it shows `ExecStart=/home/vue-client (code=exited, status=2)` instead of `203`

Comment: You did not have permission to traverse the `/root` directory before, because it your user or group did not have execute permission on the directory. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory Now you are getting exit code 2 instead of 203. You should review your app to understand under what conditions it exits with exit code 2.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. As for exit code 2, since it works perfectly when simply running the binary as root, I guess the problem must be that inside the binary, the code still try to access files that are located within the `/root/../..` directory? I feel 95% certain that must be it.. will test it tomorrow :)

Comment: What was the conclusion?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I concluded by accepting your answer :p.. the problem was the permissions, and it worked after moving everything to the `/home/` folder and setting `myservice` group as the owner of all the files in that folder.. thanks a lot, really appreciated your help :)!